# If value is in dictionary add the key in an array else add the value to a different list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'B':2, 'C': 3, 'D':4, 'E': 5}
```

This following code of mine:

```
arr = " a b c" 
arr_list = [d[a] for a in arr.split(" ")]
```

gives me this output:

```
 [1 2 3]
```

But when I pass in the following string:

```
arr = " a b c 1125"
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: '1125'
```

which makes sense as there is no key for 1125 in my dictionary. But what I want to do is pass in the following to my function:

```
arr = "a b c 1125"
```

and get the following output:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
```

and then a another list with the value with no key to it

```
list2 = [1125]
```

So in summary some help me figure how to get the value with no key in my dictionary to be added to a new list and the values with keys added to another list?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first I thougt that [@ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51053604/7655838) may be the fastest answer and if you don't like to try and catch errors you could do one of my examples:

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
d = {'a': 1, 'B':2, 'C': 3, 'D':4, 'E': 5}
arr = " a b c 1125"
for e in arr.split(" "):
    if e in d.keys():
        list1.append(d[e])
    else:
        list2.append(e)
```

(You can do two list comprehension if you are willing to sacrifice a bit more of speed for the sake of fewer code lines...)

```
d = {'a': 1, 'B':2, 'C': 3, 'D':4, 'E': 5}
arr = " a B C 1125"
list1 = [d[e] for e in arr.split() if e in d]
list2 = [e for e in arr.split() if e not in d]
```

But now I have done a test with `timeit.timeit` and I discover to my surprise that actually that wasn't the fastest way.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'B':2, 'C': 3, 'D':4, 'E': 5}
arr = " a b c 1125"
# Functions
# ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit

    print(timeit.timeit("a()", setup="from __main__ import a"))
    print(timeit.timeit("b()", setup="from __main__ import b"))
    print(timeit.timeit("c()", setup="from __main__ import c"))
    print(timeit.timeit("D()", setup="from __main__ import D")) # D instaed of d because that is the OP dictionary
```

Where `a()` was my first function, `b()` my second one, `c()` [@ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51053604/7655838) and `D()` was [@Mike Robinsy answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51053692/7655838). The output was:

```
2.4083618169348338
2.548082368010459
3.629124371952302
1.7721276028098547
```

So, the faster is Mike, then me and finally Whack. But it's your decision to choose your coding style: try-catch, loop and comprehensions, or sets and `&`.

Answer (score 1):

just have an statement like:

```
if not element in d.keys()
    list2.add(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use two separate list comprehensions with conditional statements

```
In [518]: d = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': 3, 'D':4, 'E': 5}

In [519]: arr = ' a b c 1125'

In [520]: list1 = [d[a] for a in arr.split() if a in d]

In [521]: list1
Out[521]: [1, 2, 3]

In [522]: list2 = [a for a in arr.split() if a not in d]

In [523]: list2
Out[523]: ['1125']
```

Note that the contents of `list2` will be of type `str` unless you explicitly cast them to an `int`. This is because `arr` is of type `str` which can be achieved like so:

```
list2 = [int(a) for a in arr.split() if a not in d]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate using [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
arr = "a b c 1125"

xs = set(arr.split())
keys = set(d)

print xs & keys
print xs - keys
```

Outputs:

```
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
set(['1125'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
d = {'a': 1, 'B':2, 'C': 3, 'D':4, 'E': 5}
arr = " a b c 1125"
for e in arr.split(" "):
    try:
        list1.append(d[e])
    except KeyError:
        list2.append(e)
```

Try this